# WdsClient: There was a problem initializing wds mode

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-7, wds

Having an issue with deploying windows 7 through WDS on Windows Server 2003.

I can boot to the PXE fine, have captured an image connects through DHCP fine. Capture image is on the WDS server, modified etc.

I run into an issue when actually trying to install an image to a PC. It loads, sees the boot image, appears to load the boot image, then during the "Starting Windows" screen, after about 10 seconds it throws an error. "WdsClient: There was a problem initializing wds mode"

I've tried recreating the boot image, using a discover image, all to no avail.

I've seen this question asked before on other boards, but no answers posted.

Any Thoughts?

Comment: I've seen a few posts on this and some mention that the install image does not have the appropriate network drivers. Not the case here, Shift+f10 opens a command prompt, I have an IP address and can ping the WDS server by IP and FQDN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone must've attempted to configure pxeboot before this and on our DHCP server they had previously configured option 067 to use pxeboot.com This would not work for some reason and when I changed the boot image under option 67 to use wdsnbp.com it magically worked.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732351(WS.10).aspx

The above link is a technet article on configuring network boot properly. Not really sure as to why this would allow me to capture using that boot image, but not install. But hey, it works.